# Hive box items are not restored when I factory reset my android phone and restore app data

Tags: flutter, android-backup-service, flutter-hive

I have an Flutter app where I store some data using Hive. It seemed everything worked fine. But it happened when I factory reset my android phone.

Here's what I did.

1. Data backup at Setting
2. Factory reset my phone
3. Restore data

What I expected was that Step 3 would restore the Hive box items as well. But I could not see them when I opened my app. I have no idea why it happened. Can anyone explain it? and how can I fix it?

main.dart

```
void main() async {  
  //Hive box open
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(NoteModelAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(NoteSettingAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<NoteModel>('mynote');
  await Hive.openBox<NoteSetting>('mysetting');
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: I belive when you do a factory reset your box data will be lost. There is no way you can retrive it. The best way is use a backend server where you can backup the files weekly or daily

Comment: I know I'm late to the party but factory resetting is totally wiping phone data, so that's to be expected. To persist data, you need to store it on a server, that's why solutions like Firebase exist.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#Files
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup#ImplementingBackup